# Jenkins-Testlink integration - HTTP server returned unexpected status: Found

Tags: jenkins, integration, testlink

I’m trying to connect Jenkins (1.482) with TestLink (1.9.4) thru Jenkins configuration in order to retrieve tests, but while running the job in Jenkins I get the below error in the console log.

Please note that Jenkins is hosted on tomcat (linux) on network“gnb” and Testlink is hosted on php (linux) on another network “<company network name>”. It works well when both are on my localhost (in windows)
but this integration does not work when both Jenkins and TestLink are on separate networks/hosts.

I get the below error on the console while running the job:

```
Preparing TestLink client API.
Using TestLink URL: http://<hostname>/mr61_php5/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc.php

FATAL: Error verifying developer key: HTTP server returned unexpected status: Found
br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.util.TestLinkAPIException: Error verifying developer key: HTTP server returned unexpected status: Found
        at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.MiscService.checkDevKey(MiscService.java:66)
        at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.TestLinkAPI.(TestLinkAPI.java:162)
        at hudson.plugins.testlink.TestLinkBuilder.getTestLinkSite(TestLinkBuilder.java:244)
        at hudson.plugins.testlink.TestLinkBuilder.perform(TestLinkBuilder.java:134)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:717)
        at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
        at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1502)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:236)
Caused by: org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransportException: HTTP server returned unexpected status: Found
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.getInputStream(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:94)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:152)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:143)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:69)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:56)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:167)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:158)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:147)
        at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.BaseService.executeXmlRpcCall(BaseService.java:90)
        at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.MiscService.checkDevKey(MiscService.java:62)
        ... 12 more
ERROR: Error communicating with TestLink. Check your TestLink configuration.
```

I have below settings in my Jenkins’s global configuration for Testlink installation

```
Name: testlink
URL: http://<host name>/mr61_php5/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc.php
Developer key: generated from Testlink (Settings->Generate a new key)
```

Can you please point me if I miss something?

Answer (score 3):

Usually in the Testlink folder structure, the path that you have mentioned, does not contain the xmlrpc.php file

Probabaly worng URL: URL: http:///mr61_php5/testlink/lib/api/

The correct URL is usually of this format
.../testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc//xmlrpc.php

Kindly check the correct URL, or try opening the xmlrpc.php page, so that you can get the correct path of the file. As per my assumption it should be somewhat like this:

http:///mr61_php5/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/xmlrpc.php

[image: This is how the API looks like with the xmlrpc.php file]

Comment: Thanks Shubhankar Raj. We can find the xmlrpc.php with help of login page http://<ip-address>/xampp/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/

Answer (score 0):

Good answer In my case it is as below...

http://IP:PORT/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php in 1.9.11 version of testlink

Comment: The link might change at some point so it would be better if you added the essential parts to your answer.